# Is it possible to get Authentication as json response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

currently it returns String but I'd like to send response as json to client. it api check the jwt's authentication. it appears email,nickname etc as string now.

```
 @GetMapping("/api/user/checkJWT") //    
 @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", paramType = "header", required = true)
    public String list() {

        Authentication user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        User user2 = (User) user.getPrincipal();
        return user.getAuthorities().toString() + " / " + user2.getEmail() + " / " + user2.getNickname() +  " / " + user2.getEmailVerification().getVerified();
    }
```

Comment: Can't you use, `public User list() {`, and `return user2;`? Json Object should be returned by Spring View Resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use org.json.simple.JSONObject
create a jsonobject and put everything inside it as key value pair and return it to client as json.

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put(key, value);
         .......// more values to add here
        return obj.toJSONString();
```

Comment: I keep getting error 'Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 11 path'

Comment: add code which is causing this error and if my posted answer solves your initial question please accept it as the answer and we can then have a look at this new error